# Multiple nested dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary

In my application there can be multiple servers to connect to. Each server can have more repositories, that can be opened in the app. I have a few objects for wrapping the logic of calling webservices on the repository in a concrete server and they are singletons (this is unimportant).
The app will usually handle 0-5 servers which each will have 0-5 repos. The number of objects are 5.

I want to store these objects in a class, but the

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<type, IServiceProvider>>>
```

seems a bit weird... Am I only paranoid or is this really a bad idea?

Comment: @MartinLiversage - thanks for corecting my EN :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have aggregate keys as long as you define equality and hashcode appropriately (or for simplicity even use a struct instead):

```
class ServiceProperties
{
    public int ServerId {get;set;}
    public int RepositoryId {get;set;}
    public type ServiceType {get;set;}

    //define equality, hashcode
}
```

Now you can just use a `Dictionary<ServiceProperties, IServiceProvider>`

Answer (score 3):

The declaration is a bit long and difficult to read, but as such this is OK code.

For better readability and usability consider creating a class or struct that represents this structure and has better naming.

Comment: +1 thanks for answer :) first i didnt see what you mean, but BrokenGlass gived the same with code :)

Answer (score 2):

Depends. On the one hand, a `Dictionary` (or other associative container) might feel like the correct tool for the job. On the other hand, even if your access patterns are perfectly matched to such a structure you still don't *need* the performance; all data structures are fast for such a ridiculously small number of items.

So, if you don't actually index into that tree of dictionaries all the time in your code, you could instead have a `List` of these and simply perform a linear search every time you need to:

```
class Wrapper
{
    public string Server { get; set; }
    public string Repository { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public IServiceProvider Provider { get; set; }
}
```

It's also totally possible that due to your particular access patterns this might not really make your code more readable. Visualize (or prototype) both approaches and pick the one that feels better to use.

Comment: +1 this could be used too nicely, but the accepted answers sollution looked more practical for my purpose :) but still thanks for answer